# can't add event listeners to elements using querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, mouseover, onmouseover

I'm trying to add a `mouseover` event on some links with the `data-hide-links` attribute, but it's not working at all.

I know that **my loop is working fine** and that it selects the right elements because I can `console.log()` the elements that I want. I also know for sure that **the event listener is not adding to the element** because when I look at the prototype of the elements the `onmouseover` property is `null`

Here's the code:

```js
let hideLinks = document.querySelectorAll("[data-hide-cursor]");
for (let i = 0; i < hideLinks.length; i++) {
  hideLinks[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    document.getElementById("cursor").classList.add("hide");
  });
}
```

```css
#cursor {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#cursor>div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  background: black;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.35s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor" data-cursor>
  <div></div>
</div>
<button data-hide-cursor type="submit" class="submit-mail">
  Submit
</button>
```

I tried to deconstruct the elements into an array using `let [...hideLinks] = ...` but it did not change a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine. Class `hide` just doesn't do anything

```js
let hideLinks = document.querySelectorAll("[data-hide-cursor]");
for (let i = 0; i < hideLinks.length; i++) {
  hideLinks[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    document.getElementById("cursor").classList.add("hide");
  });
}
```

```css
#cursor {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#cursor>div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  background: black;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.35s ease;
}

#cursor.hide {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor" data-cursor>
  <div></div>
</div>
<button data-hide-cursor type="submit" class="submit-mail">
  Submit
</button>
```